# Using a variable on next page before the if(isset statement

Tags: php, variables

I have a file upload form, which includes a field for the user ID.

When I submit the form to the script page to handle the upload, I need to reference the id in the $target_dir (target directory) variable.

I have tried passing the id variable to the script page, then tried echoing it into the $target_dir, it fails.

Is there another way I can get the id variable to work there?

Script Page (form handler):

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id']; /* Not sure this is the correct way to reference the id in this case */

/* Need to have id below. Example: $target_dir = "22/";  if user id was 22, and inlcuded in 
   the 'id' field from previous form page. */

$target_dir = "id_should_go_here/"; 

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

function get_next_file_number($target_dir)  {

    $files = scandir($target_dir);
    if (false === $files) { 
        return -1;
    }
    $counter = 0;
    unset($files[0], $files[1]);
    natsort($files); 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        ++$counter;
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name = $file_info['filename'];
        if ($file_name != $counter) {
            $old_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
            $new_name = $target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $counter;
            if (!file_exists($new_name)) {
                rename($old_name, $new_name);
            }
            else {

            }
            //echo "renamed: " . $old_name . " to " . $new_name, "<br>";
        }
    }
    return $counter + 1;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 

    if($check !== false) { $uploadOk = 1; } /* if file is an image */

    else { echo "File is not an image."; $uploadOk = 0; }

  }

if (file_exists($target_file)) { echo "File Already Exists."; $uploadOk = 0; }


if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) { echo "File Too Large."; $uploadOk = 0; }


if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && 
$imageFileType != "gif" ) { echo "Only Images Allowed."; $uploadOk = 0; }


if ($uploadOk == 0) { echo "File Not Uploaded"; }

   else {

$next_number = get_next_file_number($target_dir);

$new_target_file = $target_dir . $next_number;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $new_target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has 
been uploaded.";
}
// .....

  else { echo "Error Uploading File."; }

       }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be simply:

```php
$target_dir = "{$id}/";
```

you should check if the ID is a valid one and it's not empty, etc (#validate).